# A Question on a second countable $T_2$ space

Tags: general-topology

I have a question:

Does a second countable $T_2$ space $X$ always have a $G_\delta$-diagonal?

(If $X$ is regular, then it is metrizable, and it obviously has a $G_\delta$-diagonal.)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think that the answer may not be known; the authors of [this recent paper](www.ndsy.cn/jsfc/linsuo/LSPapers/LSp190.pdf) [PDF] did not know. On page $25$ they do give an example of a second countable Hausdorff space that does not have a regular $G_\delta$-diagonal, though it does have a $G_\delta$-diagonal.

Comment: This question now has a [negative answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/410704/second-countable-vs-g-delta-diagonal) at MathOverflow: Taras Banakh shows that the quotient of $\Bbb R^\omega\setminus\{0\}^\omega$ (with the topology inherited from the product topology on $\Bbb R^\omega$) by the equivlence relation $x\sim y$ iff $\Bbb R x=\Bbb R y$ is a counterexample.